# How can i get the ScanResult at a specific position in Android Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am facing another Problem with Bluetooth Low Energy at Android.
I Need to read the payload, especially the mManufacturerSpecificData and the Values stored in a Byte[]. 
What i did so far is simply:

```
private void processResult(@NonNull ScanResult result) {
        ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
        if (scanRecord == null) {
            return;
        }
        String deviceAddress = result.getDevice().getAddress();

        BleDevice bleDevice;
        if (!bleDeviceMap.containsKey(deviceAddress)) {
            bleDevice = new BleDevice(deviceAddress,result.getDevice().getName(), result.getRssi());
            bleDeviceMap.put(deviceAddress, bleDevice);
        } else {
            //bleDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).lastSeenTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            bleDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).rssi = result.getRssi();
        }
        byte[] payloadData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(1);
        showData(deviceAddress, payloadData);
    }
```

In Debug mode i can see the values for every Bluetooth device detected. But i want to save parse and work with them. So i want to getMaufacturerSpecificData of device "One" if device One is clicked.

My devices i saved in a list and displayed with deviceName address and rssi.

Maybe anyone can help me?

Comment: I got the ProtocolDataUnit now by     using scanRecord.getBytes()